# How to get wikipedia content in text box in C#

Tags: c#, regex, wikipedia

I want to download the content of the wikipedia api page and show its to text box by replacing characters from the page.

Example : Link to page

> http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext=1&titles=stack%20overflow

I want that all unwanted stuff like

```
{"query":{"normalized":[{"from":"stack overflow","to":"Stack overflow"}],"pages":{"1436888":{"pageid":1436888,"ns":0,"title":"Stack overflow","extract":
```

should be replaced.

I've tried this but its not working for this page

```
textbox1.Text = XDocument.Parse(new Regex("[[(.*?]]").Matches(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext=1&titles=stack%20overflow")[0].Value).Root.Value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get at the text would be to deserialize the response using JSON. Here is an example using Newtonsoft JSON parser. Since you are not interested in the full response, you only need to deserialize the parts necessary to get you to the node name "extract".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext=1&titles=stack%20overflow"))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
            Result result = ser.Deserialize<Result>(new JsonTextReader(reader));

            foreach(Page page in result.query.pages.Values)
                Console.WriteLine(page.extract);
        }
    }
}

public class Result
{
    public Query query { get; set; }
}

public class Query
{
    public Dictionary<string, Page> pages { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{   
    public string extract { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a Fiddle of the code working: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xGv7lG

Answer (score 0):

It's no XDocument/XML that you get but JSON.

You can create a C# class for your JSON here: http://json2csharp.com/

Download the NuGet package for Newtonsoft JSON

So you can do

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourJsonRootClass>(rawJsonString);
```

Then you can access the content of the page in your "deserialized object".

Alternatively you can also dynamically parse the JSON, but I won't explain this here now.